# Using innerHTML not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile-safari

I am using jQuery to process an AJAX request like so:

```
function success_callback(p){
    $.ajax({url:"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + p.coords.latitude.toFixed(2) + "," + p.coords.longitude.toFixed(2) + "&sensor=true",success:function(result){
        var locationInfo = eval ("(" + result + ")");
        document.getElementById("zip-number").innerHTML = locationInfo.results[0].address_components[7].short_name;
    }});
}
```

This code successfully writes the value of the found zip code into the div with the ID zip-number on the computer. When I access the site on the iPhone however it just shows blank even though I allowed my location to be shared. Any ideas why?

Comment: `eval` Its very bad to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a cross-domain AJAX request, which is normally not allowed due to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). One way to avoid this is using [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). This URL does support CORS (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` header), but mobile safari [sends an OPTIONS](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Articles/XHR.html) request to the server first, which is not supported by maps API backend.

Other way to solve this problem is using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but it's [not supported by the service anymore](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1872#c9).

**The best way to use that geocode service is by using [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) from [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), with that you wont have any cross domain request issues as the library manages those requests by itself.**